# Streams and arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two sample text and two codes I want to merge them in order to get one result .
can we cancatenate two arrays with different length ?

starting by the first one :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:/Test.txt");
    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicReference<String> g1 = new AtomicReference<>("");
    Files.lines(path) // UTF-8 file
            .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(arr -> arr.length == 3)
            .filter(arr -> arr[0].startsWith("A-")
                            || (arr[0].isEmpty() 
                            && !data.isEmpty()))
            .forEach(
                arr -> {
                    if (!arr[0].isEmpty()) {
                        g1.set(arr[0]);
                    }
                    System.out.printf("%-7s %5s %5s%n", 
                                      g1, arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
                    arr[0] = g1.get();
                    data.add(arr);
            });

    for (String[] ary : data) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary));
    }
}
```

the sample text one look like :

```
START                              
                                   
ELEMENT                            
                                   
G1      G2      G3                 
A-0     FX      0                  
        FX      1                  
A-20    FY      0                  
        FY      1                  
                                   
END
```

the second code is :

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("C:/Test.txt");
    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicReference<String> g1 = new AtomicReference<>("");
    Files.lines(path) // UTF-8 file
            .map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(arr -> arr.length == 4)
            .filter(arr -> arr[0].startsWith("A-")
                            || (arr[0].isEmpty() 
                            && !data.isEmpty()))
            .forEach(
                arr -> {
                    if (!arr[0].isEmpty()) {
                        g1.set(arr[0]);
                    }
                    System.out.printf("%-7s %5s %5s%n", 
                                      g1, arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
                    arr[0] = g1.get();
                    data.add(arr);
            });

    for (String[] ary : data) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary));
    }
}
```

the sample text 2 look like  :

```
DATA                           
                            
VRRP                        
                            
G1    G4   G5    G6         
A-0   2    B24   96         
                            
   P1   P2      P3        
   VC           NO          
                            
G1    G4   G5   G6          
A-20  5    C52  96          
                            
   P1   P2      P3        
   VC           NO          
                            
END
```

I want to get at once the bellow result by merging two text samples and there codes ( text1 & text2)
toghter .

```
A-0     FX      0   
A-0     FX      1   
A-20    FY      0   
A-20    FY      1   
A-0     2      B24  
A-20    5      C52
```

thanks

Comment: Have you actually tried concatenating them?

Comment: I'm probably from the old school, but I don't think these monstrous constructions belong to Java at all.

Answer (score 0):

> can we cancatenate two arrays with different length ?

Isn't a direct answer to your question but you can concatenate arrays of different lengths like this:

```
String[] one = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4"};
String[] two = {"9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "0"};

String[] concatenated = new String[Math.max(one.length, two.length)];

for (int i = 0; i < one.length || i < two.length; i++)
{
    concatenated[i] = "";

    if (i < one.length)
        concatenated[i] = concatenated[i] + one[i];

    if (i < two.length)
        concatenated[i] = concatenated[i] + two[i];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(concatenated));
```

Output: `[09, 18, 27, 36, 45, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`